# IdentityServer4 redirect validator - implementing IRedirectUri interface

Tags: identityserver4

I implemented a custom redirect validator (implemented interface IRedirectUriValidator) and injected it into IdentityServer4 (I'm aware of the risk that needs to be mitigated with covert redirect attacks) with the following, on the IdSrv4 host in Startup.cs, ConfigureServices():

```
services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddRedirectUriValidator<MyCustomValidator>()
```

Even though I can get it to trigger following playing with client redirectUris / server side client config quite a bit, unless the redirectUri asked for by the client is in the server side client config's "RedirectUris" list, my redirectUri validator never gets triggered because the client will be rejected first.

Seems to defeat the point of a redirect Uri validator.  Is there a way to completely override this behavior besides just implementing this interface / injecting it into the authentication flow?

Comment: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/2100

Comment: I still need to test out IdentityServer's sample for this.

Comment: Check all of the services and calls you're making before and after `AddIdentityServer` (and also check IS4's source-code to see what services that `AddIdentityServer` adds too) (e.g. pause the debugger right before `AddIdentityServer` is called and inspect the services collection) - I think that's why it's using the default `IRedirectUriValidator`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the suggestion Dai.  I didn't know what to do at the time so what we ended up doing was just making a service that adds a client to IdSrv when requested.  So basically just using the default redirect validator and because the client has its own redirectUri, that works.

Comment: I'll definitely get in there and check out the change in services when I get a minute though.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the interface from scratch or did you, like I did, inherited from the StrictRedirectUriValidator?

I ask as I had the same problem just this week using IdentityServer 3.1.2 until I realised I hadn't added the "override" modifier to the IRedirectUriValidator method signatures that I overrode.

```
public **override** async Task<bool> IsRedirectUriValidAsync(string requestedUri, Client client)
{
   ...
}
```

It worked after that. Such a silly error but they do happen. Hope this helps someone.

Comment: I don't remember.  It was a long time ago, no longer have that code base at hand.  Sorry.